# Confusion over an exterior derivative product

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I have an elementary question regarding the exterior derivative which confuses me. I am reading Theorem 2.1.13 of the book [Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory by Robb J Muirhead](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=TKVfbEvrgu4C&oi=fnd&pg=PP2&dq=aspects%20of%20multivariate%20statistical%20theory&ots=4wWznAyXnQ&sig=4RosXxNAf3IGViGVwEMKYrc8oMw#v=onepage&q=theorem%202.1.13&f=false). The part that confuses me is as follows.

$h_1, h_2,\dots,h_m,h_{m+1},\dots,h_n$ are column matrices of the same dimension of variables. Equation (22), as shown pasted below, then writes
$$\bigwedge_{j=m+1}^n\bigwedge_{i=1}^m h_j'dh_i,$$
where $'$ indicating transpose of a matrix. Each $dh_i$ appears repeatedly in the exterior product over $j$. Should that imply this expression vanishes? Yet, the author does not seem to claim so.

Below is the aforementioned theorem and the part of the proof I am confused over.

[image]
[image]

In the proof, from the sentence "First consider the matrix ..." to Eq. (22), $H$ is taken as a matrix without imposing the condition $H'H=I$.

As an example, let $n=3,\, m=1$ and $H=[h_1,h_2,h_3]$ where $h_i$ is of dimension $3$. The double exterior derivative product in Eq. (22) becomes 
$$\big(h_{1,2}\,dh_{1,1}+h_{2,2}\,dh_{2,1}+h_{3,2}\,dh_{3,1}\big)\wedge \big(h_{1,3}\,dh_{1,1}+h_{2,3}\,dh_{2,1}+h_{3,3}\,dh_{3,1}\big).$$
The associative rule does apply, right? Is the following identity wrong? Why?
$$h_{1,2}\,dh_{1,1}\wedge h_{1,3}\,dh_{1,1}=h_{1,2}h_{1,3}(dh_{1,1}\wedge dh_{1,1}).$$

I would appreciate an elucidation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, definitely not. Remember that $h_i$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$, and so $dh_i$ will have linearly independent entries in each slot. In particular, $H_1$ (in the source's notation) is an $n\times m$ matrix with orthonormal column vectors. Note that this giant wedge product will be an $m(n-m)$-form built out of all the $dx_{ki}$, where $x_{ki}$ is the $k$th entry of the column $h_i$.

Also, note that the order (and range) of the author's wedge product is different from yours. He has $1\le i\le m$ and then, for each $i$, $i+1\le j\le n$. Regarding your example, here, then $n=3$ and $m=1$. Now $h_1$ is a unit vector in $3$-space, so it varies over the $2$-sphere; we expect to get a nonzero $2$-form here. And, in fact, we do: Remember that what you've written makes no sense. You need $h'_2dh_1 = dh_1\cdot h_2$, which is the dot product of $h_2$ with $dh_1$; since $h_2$ and $h_3$ are orthogonal, they give a basis for the tangent plane of the sphere at the point $h_1$, and this wedge product is precisely the area $2$-form for the sphere. (You are, I think, forgetting about the vector nature of everything here.)

Comment: I am still not clear. I added a simple example to my question. Can you answer to that example? Thank you.

Comment: OK, I was sloppy in my answer. We're working with matrices with orthonormal column vectors, not general invertible matrices. I've edited.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, Ted. I added the relevant part of the book to my question. My question concerns Eq. (22). I have edited my simple example. Hopefully it helps you to understand exactly where I am confused.

Comment: I don't understand your computation. I explained to you in the second paragraph what should be happening here. Writing out coordinates isn't very helpful here. Where are you using the fact that $h_1,h_2,h_3$ gives you an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$? Of course $dh_{1,1}\wedge dh_{1,1} = 0$, but you get three terms with coefficients times $dh_{1,1}\wedge dh_{2,1}$, $dh_{1,1}\wedge dh_{3,1}$, and $dh_{2,1}\wedge dh_{3,1}$. This is like writing the area $2$-form on the sphere as $x dy\wedge dz + y dz\wedge dx + z dx\wedge dy$. $h_1 = (x,y,z)'$ here.

Comment: Oh, darn, the cross terms! So stupid of me! I can't believe I have been so blindsided by and fixated on the repeated terms and ignoring the obvious right in front of my eyes... :-( Thank you, Ted!

Comment: @Hans: You're welcome!